# Send the string to url with Android and get response in EditText

Tags: android, json

I need to use this api,

```
"http://sconysoft.com/api/md5.php?q="
```

for doing something like this app :

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sconysoft.md5encoderdecoder&hl=en
```

Actually, i have one button with Two `EditText` in Android app, just i need send first string to this api, and ***if this hash encoded(in url***) exist, show that in `Edit Text2`.
and this is above app Codec class :

```
public class Codec {



    public String decode(String md5) throws Exception {
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet("http://sconysoft.com/api/md5.php?q=" + md5));
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(br.readLine());

            if(jo.getString("md5").equals(""))
                throw new Exception();

            return jo.getString("word");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        throw new Exception("Can't decode given md5");
    }

}
```

main :

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) 
          getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
public void decode(View view) {
        final EditText etWord = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit1);
        final EditText etMd5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit2);

        if(!isNetworkAvailable()) {
            etWord.setText("Network unavailable");
            return;
        }

        final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(view.getContext(),"Waiting for Server", "It should take a few seconds");

        Thread th = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Codec cd = new Codec();
                    String md5 = etMd5.getText().toString();
                    try {
                        final String word = cd.decode(md5);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                etWord.setText(word);
                                pd.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (final Exception e) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                etWord.setText(e.getMessage());
                                pd.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            pd.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };
        th.start();
    }
}
```

i also try this codes with same situation in developing, but unfortunately, this codes doesn't work and i cannot see this buttons codes or other something on this app codes.

Can someone help me, how to doing this with one button and Two EditTexts?

Need some help about doing this with above API.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming

```
public void decode(View view)
```

gets called from the button onClick?

I suggest doing the network call (and managing the progress dialog) in an AsyncTask. Examples:

[Using AsyncTask for android network connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681189/using-asynctask-for-android-network-connection)

[How to use AsyncTask to show a ProgressDialog while doing background work in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893626/how-to-use-asynctask-to-show-a-progressdialog-while-doing-background-work-in-and)

You update the second EditText (you could use TextView) in the AsyncTask's onPostExecute.